# Accessing keys and values from nested hashmaps in Java

Tags: hashmap

I have a nested hashmaps in the below format in my code. When the code is executed, this class also gets executed.

```
public class NestedHashMap
{
   HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> map1 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>();

public void hashMapData()
{
 HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> map2= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

 // map3 contains key as 'Student Exam Code' and value as 'Student Name'.
    // map3.put("1352", "ABCDE");
    // map3.put("4581", "JDWEF");
    // map3.put("1587", "OWELW");
 // map2 contains key as 'Exam Centre Code' and value as map3.
    // map2.put("CENTRE092", map3);
 // map1 contains key as 'Exam Paper Code' and value as map2.
    // map1.put("ENG02", map2); 

 // The data in each hashmap is stored through for loop.
}

public void getData()
{
  String strValue = map1.get("ENG02").get("CENTRE092").get("1352");
  system.out.println(strValue);
}      

}
```

I am getting the below error when the method 'getData()' gets executed.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.HashMap.get(Object)" because the return value of "java.util.HashMap.get(Object)" is null
at scripts.NestedHashMap.getData(NestedHashMap.java:159)

Could someone please help to sort this issue out?